# Is reading SharedPreferences expensive?

Tags: android

Would reading SharedPreferences every two hours or so alongside polling in an android application be wasteful of a user's resources?

Comment: I don't think doing any simple computation every two hours is going to waste anything significantly.

Comment: I stored and would like to access an arraylist of objects. I don't know if that would exactly be considered a simple computation.

Comment: Yes, it would. It's nothing for a modern CPU to process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it, is not significantly expansive about computation.

Of course, it depends on your data; if you store a huge JSON data structure,  the read will be more weight than if you use a couple of strings.

How many information you have to store? If this information is not too much is not a problem for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was using Google's GSON library to store an arraylist of objects. Do you think this would be expensive to check occasionally? I do have other methods which don't require sharedpreferences. Do you think I should resort to those instead?

Comment: I think you are ok,GSON is good because you can maintain the POJO, but if you think your data is too big or you aren't secure about performance you can read here http://stackoverflow.com/a/15699052/6093353 . Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so , eventually your SharedPreferences are going to be stored in an XML file , key and value pairs , bigger data structures is better to be persisted with sqlite